# Not getting Confirmation Code on users email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using Registration Form from the link below.
https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm/tree/master/source

The only problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting the confirmation code/link on my(user) email ID.
On my other(admin) email ID, I'm getting the mail that a new user has registered. Even in my SQL, I'm receiving all the information like username, password and confirmation code. But it is not sending the confirmation code/link to the user.
Please Help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please show us your code what you have tried for Registration code and both user-admin email code?

Comment: Thank you Viren for helping me out. These are the files/code I'm using https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm/tree/master/source  And it is using PHP mailer. In the readme.txt you can see it says that I have to edit information like hostname, username, password, etc. in membersite_config.php..I did exactly the same. I didn't touch anything else. It is working properly, except sending the confirmation link to the user.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please refer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594088/not-getting-confirmation-code-on-users-email/54597910#54597910

Comment: @VirenPanchal I did exactly what you said, but as I changed the code...it stopped working and "HTML error 500" page came up. I'm using a live server and a subdomain which is www.anonymate.epizy.com it again started working when I undo the changes which you told me to do. Please help.

Comment: If it's a live server, then NO NEED to change to SMTP.

Comment: @VirenPanchal So how will I(user) get the confirmation link on my email?

Comment: In this file _fg_membersite.php_, find the `function GetFromAddress()` and make sure you have set **$from** value to valid Emaii-ID. remove  = "nobody@$host"; OR you can set it in _class.phpmailer.php_ file as `var $From              = 'info@yoursitename.com';`

Comment: @VirenPanchal I did what you said, I'm getting email on my admin account that a new user has registered but again it is not sending any confirmation mail on the user's email ID

Comment: You are getting email to Admin from here `function SendAdminIntimationOnRegComplete(&$user_rec)`. So for getting email to User, try to **debug** here in `SendUserWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)` function in _class.phpmailer.php _file. Also debug here in `function Send()` in _class.phpmailer.php file_ .

Comment: @VirenPanchal I tried to edit the code, but still is not working...In fact, again it shows me that HTML error 500 page...Please help, I don't understand what to do

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look through the code and it looks fine, you need to double check you corrected all the placeholders correctly, it might be you forgot to change one of them so now it can't push data to the users email.

I can't see what you changed the code to so unable to help you much more.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey for helping me out.
I have placed all the value like db_username, db_password, hostname, etc. I did exactly what it says in the Readme.txt.
https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm

Still, I'm facing this problem. I don't understand what to do next because if I change one more thing, It will stop working and will show the error page.

Answer (score 0):

@AnonyMate
Emails can be sent when it's the live server.

BUT if you want to set email working facility in localhost, then you have to **set SMTP configuration** as below.

**NOTE:-** *This is just basic setup for SMTP configuration. Different Email libraries may have different syntax.*

```
$mailconfig['charset']      = 'utf-8';
$mailconfig['mailtype'] = 'html';
$mailconfig['newline']      = "\r\n";

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost")
{
  //SMTP configuration
  $mailconfig['protocol']   = 'smtp';
  $mailconfig['smtp_host']  = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
  $mailconfig['smtp_port']  = 465;
  $mailconfig['smtp_user']  = 'your Gmail Email-ID';
  $mailconfig['smtp_pass']  = 'your Gmail Email-password';
}
```

So in your project, please refer **source/include/class.phpmailer.php**, change SMTP settings accordingly. Also find on which page there is an "email send" functionality. And set above variables values on that page as per that syntax.

**EDIT**:- *Found the page on which there is an email send functionality.*

**/source/include/fg_membersite.php**

In above file, in this function **SendUserWelcomeEmail(&$user_rec)**

Also in this file **/source/include/class.phpmailer.php**, make below changes.

**NOTE :- Dont't delete old data. just comment it.**

```
//var $Mailer     = 'mail';
var $Mailer       = 'smtp';

//var $Host       = 'localhost';
var $Host         = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

//var $Port       = 25;
var $Port         = 465;

var $SMTPSecure   = "ssl";

var $Username     = 'your Gmail Email-ID';

var $Password     = 'your Gmail Email-password';
```